# HTTP Request authentication for SPARQL Insert in Virtuoso endpoint

Tags: authentication, httprequest, sparql, virtuoso

I am trying to perform a SPARQL Insert in a Graph that I have loaded in Virtuoso, doing it trough a HTTP Request against the Virtuoso endpoint.

For the HTTP Request I am using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), and I have already made some SPARQL Select queries succesfully, so my problem lays on the Authentication process that I need to do for updating the Graph.

After quite a lot of research, I have seen that Virtuoso has some paths enabled for different authentication proccesses:

- `http://<cname>/sparql-auth` (SQL authentication)
- `http://<cname>/sparql-oauth` (OAuth)
- `http://<cname>/sparql-graph-crud-auth` (OAuth CRUD)
- `https://<cname>/sparql` and `https://<cname>/sparql-webid` (WebID Protocol)

I want to make it as simple as possible, so I have checked the `http://<cname>/sparql-auth` and I have been able to log in and perform an Insert query succesfully. This means (I guess) that I do not have any permission problems on my user.

When I try to do it through the HTTP Request however, I am not able to authenticate my user properly, I do not know how to specify the username and the password in a correct way.

I have also discovered that Virtuoso has, by default, the *Digest Authentication* method activated, so I changed it to the *Basic Authentication* on the `/sparql-auth` path as it is the easiest method for me. I have done this change using the `http://<cname>/conductor` of Virtuoso.

And still, I am not able to authenticate myself correctly through the HTTP Get request, receiving the *HTTP status code 401 (Unauthorized)*.

This is exatly how I make the Request:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8890/sparql-auth?query=' + encodeURIComponent(pruebaInsertQuery),{
        auth: {  // This is provided by axios, to perform an HTTP Basic auth
            username: 'myUserName',
            password: 'myPassword'
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I have gone through every tutorial and guide that Virtuoso has, but I'm really new in the SPARQL, RDF and Virtuoso world and I still get lost in everything.

Thank you in advance!!

---

*Question edited due to some of the comments:*

I have also tried it with a Post Request and nothing changes.

Another way I've tried is using the `http://myUserName:myPassword@localhost:8890/sparql-auth`format, but I get the exact same response.

I am not sure at all about if I am passing the exact same strings via the `axios` call and through the `/sparql-auth` path. Virtuoso may use some encoding that I have not found about, and I am not being able to find any example of an *SQL authentication* for Virtuoso (the type of authentication I am trying to use), not even for the Digest Authentication method, which is the default method of Virtuoso.

Nothing appears in my Virtuoso.log regarding the HTTP Requests, not even the succesful ones. I will research more about this as it may be because of the configuration that I have.

Thank you for the help!

---

*Finally found a way for getting the result I want:*

**I have not been able to find a solution to the authentication problem I stated here**, but I still needed to do those inserts, so I have finally **changed completely my approach** and created my own **Java RESTful service** as an intermediary between my application and *Virtuoso*.

I have found that *Virtuoso* provides some libraries for *Java*, and these libraries have helped me connecting to *Virtuoso* with the appropiate authorization. I also have to say that creating the service was not easy, but it finally worked.

I hope this information helps someone to think on this approach earlier, because it has caused me a big waste of time in my project. As I have said, I have solved my own problem of doing inserts through my application, but the authentication problem is still there, so feel free to add any new comments on this topic.

Comment: Get HTTP request is only for requesting not updating. Insert as an update need a Post Request imo.

Comment: It does not work with a Post HTTP Request neither... Same authentication problem...

Comment: The Digest Authentication is linked to the ./sparql-auth. On the other hand, Basic authentication is for ./sparql about the endpoints

Comment: But if I have changed the Authentication of the /sparql-auth, specifying the Basic Authentication, shouldn't it work? 
And if not, how could I do a Digest Authentication?

Comment: I take all my infos from here : http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideSPARQLEndpoints

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the replies!! But I have already visited that site... I have gone through pretty much the whole Virtuoso website, and I am still not able to make it work...

Comment: I note that axios doc has no wrapper on the auth keywords — i.e., `auth: { username: 'myUserName', password: 'myPassword' },` — not `auth: { 'username': 'myUserName', 'password': 'myPassword' },` as you have. Knowing nothing else about what you're doing… Have you tried using `http://myUserName:myPassword@localhost:8890/sparql-auth?...` at least as an experiment?  Are you 100% certain that the same strings are being passed for myUserName and myPassword via the `axios` call as via the `/sparql-auth` webform? Does anything show up in the Virtuoso log (default `virtuoso.log`)?

Comment: Sadly, the correct keywords format of axios didn't solve the problem. Also, I do have tried using `http://myUserName:myPassword@localhost:8890/sparql-auth?...`, and I still get Unauthorized... No, I am actually not certain at all that I am passing the same strings via the `axios` call and the `/sparql-auth` webform, that is my biggest proble and I actually do not know how to be sure about it. And finally, nothing regarding the HTTP Requests appears in my `Virtuoso.log` (it could be that I have to activate it, I will research it). I will edit my question with the info.

Comment: You may find [this HTTP logging info](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksRecording) of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE (combining DELETE and INSERT) via the SPARQL Query Service endpoint provided by any Virtuoso instance using the SPARQL Update Language (SPARUL).

Naturally, Virtuoso endpoints are protected by default; this is why `/sparql` didn't work for you. The `/sparql-update` endpoint is in place for basic Digest Authentication, which boils down to conventional [Role-based Access Controls (RBAC)](https://www.openlinksw.com/describe/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.openlinksw.com%2Foplweb%2Fglossary-term%2FRBAC%23this&graph=urn%3Adata%3Aopenlink%3Aglossary) scoped to Virtuoso SQL User Accounts.

To enable the much more powerful [Attribute-based Access Controls (ABAC)](https://www.openlinksw.com/describe/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.openlinksw.com%2Foplweb%2Fglossary-term%2FABAC%23this&graph=urn%3Adata%3Aopenlink%3Aglossary) functionality, which is scoped to Web-scale identities, you need to install the Enterprise Edition plus the [Virtuoso Authentication Layer (VAL)](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/ValWhatWhyHow) module (delivered by a [Virtuoso Application Distribution (VAD)](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/vaddistr/) package).

Here's a simple step-by-guide regarding ABAC functionality:

1. Download and install [Virtuoso Enterprise Edition](https://shop.openlinksw.com/license_generator/virtuoso/).
2. Download and install VAL module via its VAD.
3. Use the **System Admin → Packages** tab of  the Conductor UI to confirm that VAL is enabled.

   [image: Conductor UI for Configuring Virtuoso Authentication Layer]
4. Return to your SPARQL endpoint and attempt to perform an `INSERT` or `DELETE` targeting a Named Graph.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This totally seems to be the proper way of doing it. As I found a workaround to do it I won't change my code again to implement this, but if I need to do the same in the future I will totally try your solution.